# Variable created by 'except Exception as err' is not accessible from outside 'except' block

Tags: python-3.x, exception

When a variable is created by `except ... as variable`, one cannot access the `variable` from outside of `except` block. Why is it happening? The only way to access the value of `variable` I've found is to assign it to another variable:

```
c = 10
try:
    d = c[0]
except Exception as err:
    b = err

print(b)
print(err)
```

`print(b)` shows error message: "'int' object is not subscriptable".
But `print(err)` raises "NameError: name 'err' is not defined".

So, the question is: **why is the variable "err" gone?**

Comment: It's just designed this way. The `thing` in `for thing in collection:` will leak into outer scope, but `err` in exception handling doesn't.

Comment: Yes, this is [documented here](https://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/compound_stmts.html#except). It's an ugly solution to a potential memory leak.